# How can I remove single quotes from a column using python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to remove single quotes from data that is within a bucket before dumping the values to big query. I have tried using str.replace but this is not working for me.. here is the code

```
all_dat = pd.DataFrame()
for blob in blobs:
    dat = pd.read_csv("gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, blob.name)) 
    all_dat = all_dat.append(dat, ignore_index=True)
    all_dat = all_dat.replace('"', "")
all_dat.columns=column_names
print(all_dat)
```

The data that I am trying to remove the single quotes from looks like this

```
    Fresh_ID     Simpler_ID                Name 
   '87008'        '000280'                JaneDoe
```

I am trying to remove the single quotes so that I can just have the values without the single quotes in them, of which the end output will be

```
    Fresh_ID     Simpler_ID                Name 
     87008        000280                JaneDoe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```py
df["Fresh_ID"] = df["Fresh_ID"].str.replace(r"^'|'$", "")
```

and so on for all the columns.  The regex pattern `^'|'$` will match single quote at either the beginning or ending of the column value.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be

```py
df["Fresh_ID"] = df["Fresh_ID"].str.strip("'")
```